# Fraps like functionality for Metro style applications under Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, frame-rate, dll-injection

Tools like Fraps work with games based on OpenGL or DirectX but doesn't work with simple Windows 8 Metro style games like "Cut The Rope" or "Pirates Loves Daisies". Yes I know that "Cut The Rope" and "Pirates Loves Daisies" are using different technologies like JavaScript and HTML5 canvas but I'm really curious is it possible to build Fraps like tool for such games (some kind of canvas hack?). I would like to do 2 things:
1. Measure fps.
2. Capture screenshots.

I was reading articles about the whole [Fraps concept](http://www.ring3circus.com/gameprogramming/case-study-fraps/) and [intercepting calls to DirectX](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/directx8/article.php/c11453/Intercept-Calls-to-DirectX-with-a-Proxy-DLL.htm) but I'm not sure if its gonna work with Metro applications. Maybe I'm just wasting my time. I have 2 questions for you guys:
1. Do You think is it possible to build Fraps like tool that works with Metro style applications or games that are NOT using DirectX or OpenGL?
2. Does messing around with dxgi.dll (or other dll) could help somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Measuring [fps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415384/how-to-accurately-measure-html5-browser-framerates-fps) and [capturing screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript/4012915#4012915) can be done with JavaScript.

Comment: I have seen this before but using such approach You can only measure fps in browser (Firefox or Chrome). Sure You can locate folder under c:\Program files\WindowsApps with all .js files but You can only run this through Metro UI. I even tried to modify .js files for "Cut The Rope" but no luck. Game uses multiple requestAnimationFrame function calls, no loop, .js files are mifified etc.
I know that there is "Cut The Rope" version for IE but in the future
there will be more HTML5 applications in Windows App Store. Anyway thanks for VERY quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Fraps is able to display the framerate because of hooks it has into DirectX. HTML apps do not provide access to this same information.

I've confirmed that the free program ScreenPresso (http://www.screenpresso.com/) can record Cut The Rope just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Intel GPA (graphics performance analyzers)

http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/intel-gpa

Install it and then run the app.

There are a zillion options for graphs and stuff that I don't entirely understand (maybe it will be useful to you). If you want fps, just close the window; the program will continue running in the background.

There should be an icon in the lower right next to battery info and volume control. If you hover over it, it says your IP address. Right click on the icon for GPA and then select "Analyze Application" at the top.

A window will pop up with all the tile apps on the machine. Click on the app (don't double click) and click "run" in the bottom right.

The frame rate and resolution will be displayed in the upper left corner.

Tested and it works for Cut the Rope (I'm getting 58-60 fps). Hope this helps.