# Detecting a system window overlaying an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, optimization, render

After looking at [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzPq5_kCfow) I was curious how some of the features shown, can be implemented with JS.

One of my major questions is how can one detect another system window (like the word window, shown in the video) on the iframe.

On [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSWhvNdjAAE&feature=youtu.be) there is a hint suggesting that the technic is based on the fact that browsers optimize rendering for elements that are out of the view.

I couldn't tap into what are the exact methods/properties that are used.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: That video is 4 years old so it's potentially not possible anymore if it was an exploit that got patched.

Comment: spider.io was purchased by Google and there code is still active

Comment: take a look here http://productblog.appnexus.com/evolution-of-viewability-measurement-brought-to-you-by-the-death-of-flash/

Answer (score 7):

What I know it's possible to detect if page is in foreground or in background - or more precisely: if has focus or has not focus.

```js
var focus = true;
window.onblur = function() { focus = false; action(); }
window.onfocus = function() { focus = true; action(); }

document.onblur = window.onblur;
document.focus = window.focus;
 
function action(){
 if(focus) {
  document.body.style.background = "green";
 } else {
  document.body.style.background = "lightgray";
 }
}
```

```html
try click inside and then outside
```

The above code snippet uses event listeners [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) and [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus) for events [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) and [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur).

---

Better can be to use [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US):

- it works when switching tabs (page can detect that user has opened another tab)

> Note: While onblur and onfocus will tell you if the user switches windows, it doesn't necessarily mean it's hidden. Pages only become hidden when the user switches tabs or minimizes the browser window containing the tab.

see [Detect if browser tab is active or user has switched away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519535/detect-if-browser-tab-is-active-or-user-has-switched-away/19519701#19519701)

http://jsbin.com/lowocepazo/edit?js,output

---

For scrolling there is an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

> provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport

---

//EDIT:
Nowdays is not possible to detect such cases like for example in 1st video you posted (in 2:09) when another window is obscured some element:
 [image]

If I'm wrong, please correct me.

related:

- [How can I tell when the browser stops repainting DOM layers/nodes because they are obscured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437872/how-can-i-tell-when-the-browser-stops-repainting-dom-layers-nodes-because-they-a)
- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animated-gifs/

Comment: Thanks, you provided good info (nothing new to me) ... if it's not possible, can you try and guess what was the method they used?

Comment: Can confirm: no visible difference in requestAnimationFrame calls https://jsfiddle.net/Farbdose/u2tquxbx/ https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4514713492783104 only slows execution based on viewport coordinates not on real overlap.

Comment: The advertissement is maybe made with adobe flash.

Answer (score 4):

You have to check `document.hasFocus` and position/size of windows and screen monitor.

Maybe like this :

[image: demo]

You can try my demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/p9ahuo3t/

```
let bool = document.hasFocus();

$("p.info").text("in");
console.log(outerWidth + screenX)
if (screen.width < outerWidth + screenX) {
    bool = false;
    $("p.info").text("right side: out");
} else if ((outerWidth - innerWidth) + screenX < 0) {
    bool = false;
    $("p.info").text("left side: out");
} else if (screen.height < outerHeight + screenY) {
    bool = false;
    $("p.info").text("bottom side: out");
} else if ((outerHeight - innerHeight) + screenY < 0) {
    bool = false;
    $("p.info").text("top side: out");
}

if (currentChild && !currentChild.closed) {  
    let rectPage = {
        left:   (outerWidth - innerWidth) + screenX,
        top:    (outerHeight - innerHeight) + screenY,
        right:  outerWidth + screenX,
        bottom: outerHeight + screenY
    };

    let rectPopup = {
        left:   currentChild.screenX,
        top:    currentChild.screenY,
        right:  currentChild.outerWidth + currentChild.screenX,
        bottom: currentChild.outerHeight + currentChild.screenY
    }; 
    if (intersectRect(rectPage, rectPopup)) {
        $("p.info").text("eclipse with popup");
        bool = false;
    }
}
$page.text(pin(bool));
```

## Also :

- You can compare the time `(+new Date())` between two setInterval to detect inactive browser. [Chrome and Firefox throttle setTimeout/setInterval in inactive tabs](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/chrome-and-firefox-throttle-settimeout-setinterval-in-inactive-tabs).

Comment: Very impressive demo, however this won't work with another app window (like word for example)

Comment: @RoniGadot I'm not sure that your video was pure javascript or real. Other developpers would find the same thing.

Comment: I hope my answer helps you but in javascript we can't do do more.

Comment: @Hors Sujet, this video was made by spider.io that were aquired by Google, so I'm guessing it's real. I'm curious what was the technic.

Comment: It is strange that only one find that... http://spider.io/blog/2011/10/calling-out-to-researchersacademics It's maybe browser issue like that : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mngp2ACiZLM